# Accessing /etc/hosts with a cypress/included base image

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, cypress

I'm trying to create a Gitlab pipeline job where I perform an end-to-end test using Cypress. I'm currently using the cypress/included base image for the job because I would like the image to come with the executable for Cypress. However, at some point in the test, I want to append the test url that I'm using for the cypress test to the /etc/hosts file. When I try to do this, I get a permission denied message. My ultimate goal is to be able to run a cypress test in a pipeline job and append a test url to the /etc/hosts file. Any guidance would be appreciated.

I tried creating a custom Dockerfile where I used cypress/included as a base image and tried to add my custom user to the sudoers group. However, I realized that the file system for cypress/included only has a "wheel" group and I'm not sure if adding a user to that group would grant elevated privileges.

Heres a rough outline of the gitlab yaml file:

```
stages:
  - test

variables:
  BASE_IMAGE: cypress/included

test_job:
  stage: test
  image: $BASE_IMAGE
  script:
    - echo "Running tests..."
    - echo "127.0.0.1 your-url.com" | tee -a /etc/hosts
    - npx cypress run --configure --baseUrl="your-url.com"
```

Comment: consider using `--add-host [Hostname]:[IPAddress]` to update the hosts file rather than updating it manually I'm not sure How you could update the base image that you are using .

Comment: Thank you, @OmarAl-Howeiti. I think that's a good work around. I also found a way to add specific permissions by creating a custom image from the original cypress/included base image.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to update with a solution that I found. I created a Dockerfile to build a custom image from the cypress/included base image. I'm currently using latest. Then I used apt-get to install sudo. I then create a user and add it to the sudoer group. If you -it into the running container, you can see the Cypress binary present as well as other tools like sudo, npm, etc.

```
# using latest version of the cypress/included image
FROM cypress/included

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y sudo && \
    useradd -m customuser && \
    echo "customuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

USER customuser
```

Comment: why you are adding `customuser` you can update the hosts file directly from the `dockerfile`... I'm not sure if you want to use that user for other things

Comment: consider using `docker build --add-host` if you want only to update the hosts file.